# NullPointerException when adding to List

Tags: java, list, nullpointerexception

I am trying to iterate through a list of objects to figure out which ones are fighting each other. I am using the `checkedGladiators` list as something to compare against to prevent it from checking gladiators already assigned to a combat, as each `s` that isn't assigned already will build their entire combat around them. Currently I get a `NullPointerException`, so I used some test text to figure that it was happening right at `listContains(checkedGladiators,s)`. I added the part before it. NOW the problem is happening between "Null" and "Null Changed" as well, which makes no sense to me.

```
for (Gladiator s : gladiators) {
    if (checkedGladiators == null) {
        System.out.println("Null");
        combat1.add(s);
        checkedGladiators.add(s);   
        System.out.println("Null Changed"); 
    }
    if (listContains(checkedGladiators, s)) { 
        // if gladiator is already in a combat do nothing
    } else { // if he isn't

    }
}
```

listContains class:

```
public boolean listContains(List<Gladiator> List, Gladiator search) {
    for (Gladiator p : List) {
        if (p.equals(search)) {
        return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Does anyone know why this would occur? Thanks

Edit1:

```
public class Ai {
private List<Gladiator> gladiators;
private List<List<Gladiator>> combatsList;
private List<Gladiator> checkedGladiators;
private List<Gladiator> combat1;
private List<Gladiator> combat2;
private List<Gladiator> combat3;
private List<Gladiator> combat4;
private List<Gladiator> combat5;
private List<Gladiator> combat6;    
private List<Gladiator> combat7;    
private List<Gladiator> combat8;    
private List<Gladiator> guardList;
private List<Gladiator> advanceList;
private List<Gladiator> retreatList;
int totalCombats = 0; // total combats going on
```

I have initialized the list variable in the class already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are forgetting to create the checkedGladiators object.

So, create the object before your loop as:

List<Gladiators> checkGladiators = new ArrayList<Gladiators>();

Then, in your loop, rather than testing for checkGladiators == null...

test for checkGladiators.isEmpty().

Comment: I had initiated my gladiators list already but this did lead me to the answer as I needed to be testing for .isEmpty and I needed to call the = new List part. Thanks!

Comment: I just want to comment this answer because it's the accepted one and didn't work for me completly because however in C# is possible to do: List<Gladiators> checkGladiators = new List<Gladiators>(); in Java you must do List<Gladiators> checkGladiators = new ArrayList<Gladiators>();.

Comment: You're right... I typed too fast.  It should have been Array List.  Good catch.

Answer (score 3):

`if(checkedGladiators ==null)` is true and you are adding something to it ,

it will definitely `throw a NullPointerException` , because you are operating on null

Thanks
Abhi

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to do all this?  Why isn't this sufficient?

```
// This has your data in it.
List<Gladiators> gladiators = new ArrayList<Gladiators>();
// Obviously some attributes, including a unique key or name.  
// MUST override equals and hashcode properly
Gladiator g = new Gladiator();
if (gladiators.contains(g)) {
  // do something here.
}
```

`NullPointerException` is one of the easiest problems to fix.  Run your code in an IDE with debugging turned on and put a breakpoint where the stack trace says the exception occurred.  You'll figure out quickly why something you assumed should not be null has violated your assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

When `checkedGladiators` is `null` you try to add to it (as if it were a List/Collection/etc).

```
...
if (checkedGladiators == null) {
    ...
    checkedGladiators.add(s);   // <-- You handle 'checkedGladiators'
                                // <-- as an instaciated, when it is 'null'
```

Do this instead:

```
...
if (checkedGladiators == null) {
    ...
    checkedGladiators = new ArrayList<...>();   // <-- instanciate appropriately
    checkedGladiators.add(s);  
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking with `System.out.println`, use `StackTrace` or a `debugger` like `eclipse`. I will pin-point clearly.

```
  if (checkedGladiators == null) { 
            System.out.println("Null");
            combat1.add(s);
            checkedGladiators.add(s);  --> checkedGladiators is null here. Here null pointer exception will occur. 
            System.out.println("Null Changed"); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you check if checkedGladiators is null and then call a method on it:

```
if (checkedGladiators == null) { // <-- null!!
   checkedGladiators.add(s); // <-- null pointer exception.
}
```